# Edge split modifier with angle removes smooth shading artifacts

Tags: modeling, shaders, edges

There are these well known shading artifacts when you have edges on a flat surface and put it on smooth shading.

When I use the edge split modifier on an object and put it on the angle mode it will remove these artifacts.

When I mark the edges as sharp and use the sharp edges mode it will still show these artifacts though.

I'm just curious why it doesn't remove them then.

Comment: Any screenshot to see what do you mean by "artifacts"? Thx

Comment: Your mesh probably have triangles in those areas, try to change to quads.

Comment: @ Polosson I'm talking about the general shading "errors" when there are some tris or N-Gons.